# Symfony2 and AngularJS. Can anyone explain me?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, symfony

how are you going? 
Came here to ask you how symfony2 and angularjs can work together, because I tried to find and read about it on google and others, but I still can't understand at all.
-Is it possible?
-If it is possible, what are the advantages and disadvantages?
-symfony2-jquery or symfony2-angularjs? or both(i still don't underestand)?..
-What about twig? how can I work with the {{}} of angular (just explain me how, not the implementation)?

Comment: They can be used together, and googling "Symfony2 + AngularJS" gives you plenty of results showing different implementations. If you don't want to see how it's practically done, what is it you are actually asking? Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to revise your question for better clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the info, sorry about the "clarity" of my answer. ShinDarth already gave me the answer that I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is to implement a REST API with Symfony that provides data and then create a web application with AngularJS that consumes data from the REST API. I'm pretty sure you can find a lot of examples of that by looking on Google.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I understand how does it work, at least I get the idea

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use angular you must use `{% verbatim %} tag`
like this:

```
{% verbatim %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endverbatim %}
```

Inside tag you can write angular code

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found that in other website but I didn't get it at all. Now I understand better